# how to delete data from database using mvc3?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3, delete-row

I am new to Json datatype. how to retrive it.. please look at the code below.

This is my Javascript code:

```
function fnDeleteSelected() {
            var count_checked = $("[name = 'myChkBox[]']:checked").length;            
            var arrayOfID = [];

            $(':[name = "myChkBox[]"]:checked').each(function () {
                arrayOfID.push($(this).val());
            });            
            var test = JSON.stringify(arrayOfID);
            alert(test);
            if (count_checked == 0) {
                alert("Please Select a Student to delete");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var confirmDel = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");                
                if (confirmDel == true) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: baseUrl + "DeleteSelected/",
                        type: 'Post',
                        dataType: 'Json',
                        data: { Parameters: test },
                        success: function (msg) {
                            jQuery("input:checkbox:checked").parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });enter code here
                }
            }
        }
```

here data send to controller is parameters where parameters = ["143","144","145"]

and my controller is: where Parameters is passed as "[\"143\",\"144\",\"145\"]"my question is how to parse the Parameters so that it can be embedded in sql statement

```
public JsonResult DeleteSelected(string [] Parameters)
        {string strConn = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Information;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        string strSql = "DELETE FROM dbStudent where ID in";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(Parameters, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

what should be there in strSql..??

Comment: I would recommend using an ORM like Entity Framework. It is much easier to use and you don't have to sanitize every input for SQL injection etc.

Comment: ya it would be much easier but i am asked to do in the above format.. so could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your ajax post to be like that: (the contentType is important)

```
  jQuery.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + "DeleteSelected/",
                type: 'Post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(arrayOfID),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (msg) {
                    jQuery("input:checkbox:checked").parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
```

and your action method to be like that

```
  public JsonResult DeleteSelected(int[] Parameters)
    {
        string strConn = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Information;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        var strSql = "DELETE FROM dbStudent where ID IN (" + String.Join(",", Parameters) + ")";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(Parameters, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man but I had already solved it.. I compared our answers and it was a bit similar... hahahaha when we are in our bad mood small mistakes are not seen. But I have brainstromed abit and completed. thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array to int array

```
int[] myInts = Parameters.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Then

```
var query = "DELETE FROM dbStudent where ID IN (" +
    String.Join(",", myInts ) + ")";
```

Comment: I got an error saying Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Where u got error? put value form String.Join(",", myInts )  in one string variable and see whats the value through debugger

Comment: i just want to change the "[\"143\",\"144\",\"145\"]" to int which sql statement can accept please help

Comment: Have u tries at least List<String> instead of string array?